# How to use dynamic arrays?

Tags: c

**Q**:    Find all prime numbers between two given Numbers a and b,  by using  [Sieve of Eratosthene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Im using dynamic array to store prime numbers, but it does nt work.

After debug it, everything is ok untill the last 
   `printf()`  that  crashes.

**Code**

```
int main() {

    int i, j, n, a, b, k;
    int *tab;
    scanf("%i", &n); // n is number of sets

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        scanf("%i %i", &a, &b);

        tab = (int*) malloc(b * sizeof(int)); //allocating the memorry 

        for (j= 0; j < b; j++){             //seting all numbers to be prime
            *(tab + j) = 1;
        }

        for (j = 2; j <= b; j++){

            if (*(tab + j) == 1){
                for(k = j; k <= b; k+=j)
                    *(tab + k) = 0;     //seting 0 for all non prime numbers
            }

        }

        for (j = a; j <= b; j++){
            if (*(tab + j) == 1){
                printf("%i", j);            //printing prime numbers
            }
        }
        free(tab);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `tab` only has `b` elements. Your code accesses up to `(b+1)*(b+1)` of them. This makes no sense.

Comment: You are accessing beyond the range of the array.

Comment: please don't use `*(tab + j)`. Use `tab[j]` instead. It's the consecrated way of accessing array elements. It's much more clear and simple.

Comment: Your new code uses uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thans melpomen, I chanded the loops and tow it doesnt crash, now I have problem with the algorithm but ill try to fix it

Comment: You not initialize     `k`

Comment: dont cast result of `malloc()`.   you can use this safe way   `Type * t = malloc(     CNT *    sizeof (*t)   );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second loop should be

```
        for (j = 2; j <= b; j++){

        if (*(tab + j) == 1){

            for(k = j; k <= b; k += j)
                *(tab + k) = 0;   //seting 0 for all non prime numbers
        }

    }
```

the problem was that because you used multiplication, you tried to access an item in the tab array with index above its allocated size.

edit: and as @melpomene stated, the array is too short. therefore the allocation should be

```
            tab = (int*) malloc((1+b) * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: That still goes out of bounds.

Comment: @melpomene thanks, i added your correct comment also.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're accessing array out of its bounds:

```
 *(tab + k*j) = 0;
```

when

```
k <= b
j <= b
```

When you declare array of *b* elements, you can only access array from 0 to b-1 index.

BTW, as mentioned in comments, using `tab[k*j]` is more readable and shows clearly that tab is array.

I don't really understand what you mean by sets number, but pseudocode of Sieve of Eratosthenes taken from wiki is applied from 2 to *n*. So in your case 2 becomes *a* and *n* becomes *b*. You don't need checking all numbers from *a* to *b*, root of *b* will suffice.
Your algorithm should look like:

1. create array for holding `b - a` elements
2. make every element equals 1
3. make 0 elements which fulfill Eratosthenes rules for complex number
4. print indexes which contains 1.

Comment: Thanks im working on it. For example 2 sets of numbers mean ill do everything twice.